# Default props with wrapped Styled Component in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm working on a component that includes a couple default props and I want to pass them down to a Styled Component. Here's where I'm currently at:

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
// Icon SVG code
import Icons from "./icons";

const icons = ["add", "subtract"];

interface Props {
  className?: string;
  icon: typeof icons[number];
  size?: number;
}

const Wrapper = styled.div<Omit<Props, "icon">>(({ size }) => ({
  width: size,
  height: size
}));

const Icon: FC<Props> = ({ className, icon, size = 24 }) => (
  <Wrapper className={className} size={size}>
    <Icons icon={icon} />
  </Wrapper>
);
```

For the top-level component API, `size` should an optional prop since it has a default value (24). However, `size` should be marked as required for the `Wrapper` styled component, since React will ensure that the default value is always applied if the developer hasn't provided one.

I'm wondering if anybody has suggestions on design patterns to address this problem without having to rewrite variants of the same Interfaces multiple times. I'm also using the latest releases of all dependencies, including TS, React, and Styled Components.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the general problem you want a solution for? Your problem had a simple solution. What kind of scenario would require a repetitive solution?

Comment: Thanks for responding @aron. I should have provided a little more information. The code example I wrote above doesn't actually work. Typescript rightfully complains because `size` is an optional prop on `Icon` but is required on `Wrapper`. I know that this is completely fine because React will apply the default size value of `24`, but I don't know how to make TS aware of this. Does this clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this type might help

```
type RequireKey<T, Key> = { [K in keyof Required<T>]: K extends Key ? NonNullable<T[K]> : T[K] }
```

To create a modified version of `Props` where size can no longer be undefined you can do

```
// The original Props that is Icon's external interface
interface Props {
  className?: string;
  icon: typeof icons[number];
  size?: number;
}

// Props with "size" made mandatory
type RequireSize = RequireKey<Props, "size">

// type RequireSize = {
//   className: string | undefined;
//   icon: string;
//   size: number; <- no longer optional!
// }
```

If you now use `RequireSize` in Wrapper instead of `Props` then "size"'s type will be narrowed to `number` instead of `number | undefined`

```
const Wrapper = styled.div<Omit<RequireSize, "icon">>(({ size }) => ({
  width: size,
  height: size
}));

// Use Props as before
const Icon: FC<Props> = ({ className, icon, size = 24 }) => (
  <Wrapper className={className} size={size}>
    <Icons icon={icon} />
  </Wrapper>
);
```